# What's the difference between '/sbin/fstrim' and '/sbin/zpool trim [pool]' which trim ZFS pools?

Tags: filesystem, ssd, zfs, trim

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on ZFS and all works good. I know that Ubuntu has fstrim scheduled on a weekly basis by default but ZFS also supports trim   through '/sbin/zpool trim [pool]'. What's the difference between them and should I schedule both to trim my SSD?

Comment: christian already had an answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200172/should-i-turn-on-zfs-trim-on-my-pools-or-should-i-trim-on-a-schedule-using-syste

Answer (score 3):

To put it short, `fstrim` is a command to run trim on filesystems that support this by the kernel, such as `ext4`, `btrfs`, `f2fs` etc.

Since ZFS is more than just a filesystem (it's also a disk volume manager), it has it's own trim utility to trim a Zpool (the top component of a ZFS storage system), which is run by the `zpool trim` command.

This is needed because a mount point on a ZFS system is not necessarily equivalent to a disk (a mount point can be a pool, a subfilesystem, a snapshot etc.). And since the `fstrim` command does not know the ZFS data structure, it can't do anything on ZFS.

This is completely evident if you actually try to run `fstrim` on a ZFS mount point, which I tried below:

```
$ sudo fstrim -v /mnt/zfs/public
fstrim: /mnt/zfs/public: the discard operation is not supported
```

So this will not work. Instead, for ZFS you should set up regular trim with the `zpool trim` command, or set the ZFS property `autotrim=on` on your Zpool.

Also see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200172/should-i-turn-on-zfs-trim-on-my-pools-or-should-i-trim-on-a-schedule-using-syste) for advice on how to configure trim on your ZFS pool.