# Should I turn on zfs-trim on my pools or should I trim on a schedule using systemd timers or cron?

Tags: ssd, cron, systemd, zfs, trim

I run Ubuntu 19.10 installed on ZFS through the new ZFS install option on 19.10. This is on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th which is in heavy daily use. No dualboot so it's Ubuntu all the time. The laptop has a SSD, and as I understand it fstrim doesn't read and work on ZFS so I either have to run on trim for my pools or schedule trim with systemd timers or cron. I have used btrfs in the past and there I ran trim on a schedule since it slowed me down a little to enable discard (trim). But on ZFS enabling trim doesn't seem to give me a performance hit at all so I was wondering if I still should set up trim on a weekly or monthly basis?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [ZoL git commit](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/commit/1b939560be5c51deecf875af9dada9d094633bf7) message adding trim support:

> In addition to the manual `zpool trim` command, a background automatic
>   TRIM was added and is controlled by the 'autotrim' property. ...
>
> Since the automatic TRIM will skip ranges it considers too small there
>   is value in occasionally running a full `zpool trim`.  This may occur
>   when the freed blocks are small and not enough time was allowed to
>   aggregate them.  An automatic TRIM and a manual `zpool trim` may be
>   run concurrently, in which case the automatic TRIM will yield to the
>   manual TRIM.

so `zpool set autotrim=on` and a periodic `zpool trim` is the recommended approach.

I'd suggest a cron job (or systemd timer if you prefer) to run `zpool trim` at the same frequency as you run scrub your pool, which is set as the second Sunday of every month by default (have a look at `/etc/cron.d/zfsutils-linux`), but on different days of the month so the two aren't running simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for great help. I have now set it up as you suggest.